# VB InputBox Validation Inquiry

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

I know InputBox isn't the best for validation, but that was one of the specifications on the program I am writing for class. My problem is that despite the if or case statements I make to validate the data entered, it still accepts the data while simultaneously displaying the MsgBox's I have in my code..

Essentially what I would like the case statement to do is to properly filter the data that is entered and not proceed onto the next floor if the data is invalid and request that new data be entered. If the data is valid, proceed onto the next floor.

```
    Const ROOMS As Integer = 30
    Const MAX_FLOOR As Integer = 16
    Dim floor As Integer
    Dim StrOccupancy As String
    Dim occupancy As Integer
    Dim occupancyRate As Double
    Dim occupancySum As Integer
    Dim overallRate As Double

    lblOccupancyRate.Text = String.Empty
    lblRoomsOccupied.Text = String.Empty
    output.Items.Clear()

    For floor = 1 To MAX_FLOOR
        If floor = 13 Then
            Continue For

        End If

        StrOccupancy = Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter the number of rooms occupied for floor:" & Space(1) & floor), occupancy)

        Select Case occupancy
            Case < 1
                MsgBox("Please enter a number of 1 or more occupants.")
            Case > 30
                MsgBox("Amount of occupants must be between 1-30.")
            Case >= 1 And occupancy <= 30

                occupancyRate = (occupancy / ROOMS)
                occupancySum += occupancy
                overallRate = occupancySum / (ROOMS * 15)

        End Select
        output.Items.Add("Floor: " & floor & " Rooms Occupied: " & occupancy _
                            & " Occupancy Rate: " & occupancyRate.ToString("P2"))
            lblRoomsOccupied.Text = occupancySum.ToString
            lblOccupancyRate.Text = overallRate.ToString("P2")

    Next
    output.Items.Add("")
    output.Items.Add("Total occupancy is" & Space(1) & occupancySum & Space(1) & "and" & Space(1) & overallRate.ToString("P2") & Space(1) & " of rooms are full.")
End Sub
```

Comment: "What should I add or change in order for this to function properly?" -- Well, you haven't defined what "function properly" means.  So if its left up to me I would add a glass of rum and a couple fajitas.

Comment: The problem you have is that your` Select Case` is using the wrong variable. It should be `StrOccupancy` instead of `occupancy`

Comment: Well, I would like it to properly filter the data that is entered and not proceed onto the next floor if the data is invalid according to my case statement.. Though, alcohol and some nice fajitas do sound really nice right about now..

Comment: @3vts Not the issue. I used the TryParse method to convert the data to an integer with the variable occupancy. Either one still leaves me with the same issue.

Comment: @Sam: Fajitas and rum? No way. Tequila. I'm going to order mine now, while Gonzo considers the outcome of comments instead of making an [edit] to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough. Changes have been made.

Comment: @Gonzo: What would "not proceeding to the next floor" look like?  Just halt execution?  Ask the user to enter new data for the current floor?  Redirect Ken's fajita delivery guy to my house?

Comment: @SamAxe Yes, ask the user to enter new data for the current floor.

Comment: There's alot wrong, turn option strict on...

Answer (score 0):

Had a little time to check your code and actually you need a Boolean that validates if the occupancy requirements are met and loop if not. The code would be something like this:

```
    For floor = 1 To MAX_FLOOR
        'Boolean to validate the occupancy meet the requirements
        Dim goodOccupancy As Boolean = False
        'Do loop enters at least 1 time and runs the code inside it
        Do

            Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter the number of rooms occupied for floor:" & Space(1) & floor), occupancy)

            Select Case occupancy
                Case < 1
                    MsgBox("Please enter a number of 1 or more occupants.")
                Case > 30
                    MsgBox("Amount of occupants must be between 1-30.")
                Case >= 1 And occupancy <= 30

                    occupancyRate = (occupancy / ROOMS)
                    occupancySum += occupancy
                    overallRate = occupancySum / (ROOMS * 15)
                    'If the requirements are met we change the Boolean value to continue with the execution
                    goodOccupancy = True
            End Select
            'We loop if the requirements are not met
        Loop Until goodOccupancy = True
        output.Items.Add("Floor: " & floor & " Rooms Occupied: " & occupancy _
                        & " Occupancy Rate: " & occupancyRate.ToString("P2"))
        lblRoomsOccupied.Text = occupancySum.ToString
        lblOccupancyRate.Text = overallRate.ToString("P2")

    Next
```

But please next time try to be more explicit with your code. Most of people won't check what is going on. Do not expect people to solve your problems without guidance. Please read the [How to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it will give you a light to use the site as it is supposed to be used